# Windows Phone Screen turned black

Tags: screen, display

My windows phone just refused to show the start screen. The screen is black. If I force it at times it turns blue. I cannot call people because I cannot see anything. But when people call I can receive the call

Comment: What phone do you have? What version of Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile is it running? What do you mean by "force it"? When and how did the problem start? Is there any physical damage to the display? Have you tried restarting the phone or doing a soft reset?

Comment: I have a Microsoft Lumia 540. I force it by pressing both the power and volume switches at once. A blue screen appears and then go off. I have restarted the phone several times. There is no damage to the screen or the phone. I just connected the phone to a wifi in an Internet cafe. Then after that the phone went black. I cannot see the various tiles. But I am receiving calls okay.

Comment: If you hold the volume-up button, do you see anything on screen?  I'm thinking perhaps just the start screen is not visible for some reason, like maybe all the tiles have been removed.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I got the solution from you tube. It is like this. Switch off phone. Then press volume and power switches at the same time for 10 seconds. Phone will vibrate. An exclamation sign (!) will appear on the screen. Then press once the volume up, then volume down, then power switch and then volume down again. Two gears will appear on the screen and the phone will automatically reformat itself. The phone will become like new. You will lose some data and programmes installed on the phone. But you can reinstall everything back.

Comment: @RedeemerKowu That's a hard reset, and yes, it will restore the phone to factory settings and delete all user data. If this worked for you, consider posting it as an answer, for the benefit of others who might find this post in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem. I got the solution from YouTube. It is like this:

1. Switch off phone.
2. Then press volume and power switches at the same time for 10 seconds.
3. Phone will vibrate and an exclamation sign (!) will appear on the screen.
4. Then press once the volume up, then volume down, then power switch and then volume down again.
5. Two gears will appear on the screen and **the phone will automatically reformat itself**.
6. The phone will become like new. You will lose some data and programmes installed on the phone. But you can reinstall everything back.